# How to process JavaScript multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var givenArray = [23, 6, [2,[6,2,1,2], 2], 5, 2];
```

**INPUT:** `var givenArray` is any array, may or may not be a multi-dimensional array.

**PROCESS:** Please use HTML, CSS and JavaScript (control structure, built-in function, recursive function) to output the array elements by maintaining their level.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
23 
6  
     2
          6
          2
          1  
          2
     2
5
2
```

Comment: Can you explain 2nd and 3rd output line or whole?

Comment: If you want to maintain the level, I think the first line must be `23, 6, 5, 2` ?

Comment: This really seems like a homework question.

Comment: i can't understand how i maintain the level of the output of array element?can u explain it simply

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, following might be of some help

```
var givenArray = [23, 6, [2, [6, 2, 1, 2], 2], 5, 2];

function display(arr, indent) {
    for (var x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
        var i = arr[x]
        if (i instanceof Array) {
            display(i, indent + 4)
        }
        else {
            console.log(" ".repeat(indent) + i)
        }
    }
}

display(givenArray, 0)
```

Output:

```
23
6
    2
        6
        2
        1
        2
    2
5
2
```

Fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ekr7wwam/1/)

Comment: yeah bro..you are right..but can i use this for loop different ways.if it can how it's possible?

Comment: Depends on what is `different way`

Comment: when i am trying to run this code,my ide shows a error which is for(..) loop are not supported by current javascript version.what can i do now?

Comment: Answer updated. Try now. Which ide are you using. And most of the latest browser supports for in syntax

Comment: phpstroam..although it don't show any error, browser didn't show any result

Comment: is any line needs to add to your code for display the result?

Comment: @sourav please see fiddle link in answer.

Comment: @sourav You can upvote it and accept it as answer if helped

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a closure over the level indentation.

```js
var array = [23, 6, [2, [6, 2, 1, 2], 2], 5, 2];

array.reduce(function iter(level) {
    return function (node, item) {
        var pTag = document.createElement('p');
        pTag.style.marginLeft = level + 'px';
        node.appendChild(pTag);
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            item.reduce(iter(level || 50), pTag);
        } else {
            pTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
        }
        return node;
    };
}(0), document.body);
```

```css
p { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```